# Adjusting div according to size of the screen

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm developing an multipages web based hybrid mobile application. I'm having problem with div I need the div to adjust based on browser. That is when I minimize or reduce the size of browser I need my div to viewed same but my below code makes all elements position one above another when I minimize.

```css
#viep {
  position:relative;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#viep1 { 
  position:relative;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:auto;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#placehere {
  position:absolute;
  top:5%;
  left:30%;
}
#placehere img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-width:100%;
}
#my1 {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:35%;
  left:0;
}
.appButtons {
  position:absolute;
  top:80%;
  left:35%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    ...
    ..
  </div>
  <div id="viep">
    <div id="viep1">
      <div id="placehere" style="display:none;">
      </div>
      <table class="myt1" id="my1" style="display:none;"> </table>
      <input type="button" id="buttonid" class="appButtons" value="Reportees">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what are you trying to do :)

Comment: please try bootstrap. It will make your page responsive. So your div will adjust as per size of screen

Comment: Are you using your own css?  Why not use CSS libraries like bootstrap,  and if needed customize it.  Use Materialcss, angular-material or whatever you like,  there is a myriad of libraries ready to use that solves the media query and responsive-first issues.

Comment: I agree with Marko Mackic here.
Btw, I disagree with "just use a library". Learn css first, by just using bootstrap before knowing bare css basics, it will be hard to understand css. Testimony are the many questions about very simple fixes for bootstrap code on here.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @MarkoMackic try to develop an hybrid app for mobile and i need an div to be flexible while minimizing the browser size.my above code looks good when screen size is maximum or full when i try to minimize everthing gets overlapped

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you will need to define the viewport in your html documents with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`. In your CSS for your divs, try doing `width: 100%`. If you want something centered on your page, in your CSS add: `margin: auto`

Additionally, you can just use a framework like Foundation or Bootstrap which will make everything much easier for you. But it's always better to try learning it yourself first.